# Watershed implementation in C++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, watershed

I'm working in the watershed algortih in C++. I have implemented a source that i've found but i didn't get the expected results. I obtain:

[[image: My result]

But the result should be this:

[[image: The expected result]

I have charge the image .bmp into a matrix an then i obtain the Gradient of the image using the Sobel operator. 
My wathershed algorith now is:

```
    void Watershed() {

stack<punto> s;
punto p, neighbour;

C_Matrix prueba3 (Gradiente.FirstRow(), Gradiente.LastRow(), Gradiente.FirstCol(), Gradiente.LastCol(), -1);

int auxU, auxV, Eaux, L=1;

for (double g = Gradiente.Min(); g <= Gradiente.Max(); g++) {

    for (int i = Gradiente.FirstRow(); i <= Gradiente.LastRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = Gradiente.FirstCol(); j <= Gradiente.LastCol(); j++) {
            if (Gradiente(i, j) == g) {
                p.Guarda(i, j);
                s.push(p);
            }

            while (s.empty() == 0) {
                p = s.top();
                s.pop();
                auxU = p.x;
                auxV = p.y;
                Eaux = -1;

                // 8-connectivity
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if (i == 0)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 1)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 2)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV - 1);
                    else if (i == 3)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV);
                    else if (i == 4)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV);
                    else if (i == 5)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU - 1, auxV + 1);
                    else if (i == 6)
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU, auxV + 1);
                    else
                        neighbour.Guarda(auxU + 1, auxV + 1);

                    if (neighbour.x >= Gradiente.FirstRow() && neighbour.x <= Gradiente.LastRow()
                        && neighbour.y >= Gradiente.FirstCol() && neighbour.y <= Gradiente.LastCol()) {
                        if (prueba3(neighbour.x, neighbour.y) > 0) {
                            if (Eaux == -1) {
                                Eaux = prueba3(neighbour.x, neighbour.y);
                            }
                            else if (prueba3(neighbour.x, neighbour.y) != Eaux)
                                Eaux = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (auxU >= Gradiente.FirstRow() && auxU <= Gradiente.LastRow()
                    && auxV >= Gradiente.FirstCol() && auxV <= Gradiente.LastCol()) {

                    if (Eaux >= 0) {
                        prueba3(auxU, auxV) = Eaux;
                    }
                    else {
                        prueba3(auxU, auxV) = L;
                        L++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    C_Print("Se sale");
                    C_PrintNum("AuxU", auxU);
                    C_PrintNum("AuxV", auxV);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
C_PrintNum("L = ", L);

double max = prueba3.Max();
if (max > 255.0) {
    prueba3.Stretch(0, 255);
}

aux = C_Image(prueba3);
```

}

I don't know where is the fail, maybe my source has mistakes.

Comment: First check, about loading the image into a matrix: Do you see the original `.bmp` without applying the watershed algorithm?

Comment: Yes, the image load is ok and the gradient of the image is well calculated, i have checked it

Comment: Define variables at their point of first use. Confine their scope to where they are potentially used. Give them meaningful names.  When I see `punto p, p1, p2, p3, p4;` I lose all interest in reading further.

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. .

Comment: p is the actual coordenate, and p1 is used to represent the neighbours

Comment: ok i'll try to explain better the variables